# Change NSTextAttachment image don't work immediately even in main queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, textkit, nstextattachment

I use NSTextAttachment to Display a placeholder image . when click this image , I want to 
show another image. I do this in UItextView delegate method :

> -(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithTextAttachment:(NSTextAttachment *)textAttachment inRange:(NSRange)characterRange

I encounter below problems:
tap(click) image and already go into delegate method, but the image don't change immediately. 
I try change image in main queue and call setNeedsDisplay,But it still not work.
Please help :)

Here is my main code:

viewDidLoad:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"This is an example by @marcelofabri_"];

[attributedString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName
                         value:@"username://marcelofabri_"
                         range:[[attributedString string] rangeOfString:@"@marcelofabri_"]];

//first image
NSTextAttachment *textAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
textAttachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample_image.png"];
NSAttributedString *attrStringWithImage = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment];

[attributedString appendAttributedString:attrStringWithImage];

self.textView.attributedText = attributedString;
self.textView.delegate = self;
self.textView.editable = NO;
```

UITextView Delegate method

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithTextAttachment:(NSTextAttachment *)textAttachment inRange:(NSRange)characterRange{
UIImage *image  = textAttachment.image;

NSLog(@"width:%f , height:%f",image.size.width,image.size.height);
//change second image
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{                      

    textAttachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample_image_1"];        
    [_textView setNeedsDisplay];
});

return true;
}
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: write [_textView layoutIfNeeded] before setNeedsDisplay

Comment: even i tried the same code and its working

Comment: so strange , I found  long press placeholder image when system modal a (Save to Camera Roll)ActionShet view ,second image can showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some digging, I found textview can redrawing image by invalidating the layout manager

```
[textView.layoutManager invalidateDisplayForCharacterRange:characterRange];
```

Comment: Didn't work for me when UITextView is embedded in a UITableView.  Reloading the table works though.

Answer (score -1):

```
[textView.layoutManager invalidateDisplayForCharacterRange:characterRange];//refresh display
[textView.layoutManager invalidateLayoutForCharacterRange:characterRange actualCharacterRange:NULL];//refresh layout
```